# How to preload the images in CollectionView by generating a Thumbnail of the pdf?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I would like to create a pdfReader with a collectionview. What I want is to have a collectionview with Thumbnails of the pdf to display. So I use this in the viewDidLoad (to avoid the fact that it will generate the thumbnail in the collectionview each time we go down or up). It is generated one time, and it is without lag :

Loading the thumbnail of the pdf in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
...
 coverPdf = [NSMutableArray new];
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
        // Load image on a non-ui-blocking thread
        NSString *pdfPath = nil;
        NSURL *pdfUrl = nil;
        CGPDFDocumentRef pdfRef = nil;
        NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (id cover in filePathsArray)
        {
            pdfPath = [categoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:cover];
            pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath];
            pdfRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfUrl);
            [arr addObject:[self imageFromPDFWithDocumentRef:pdfRef]];
            NSLog(@"first process");

        }
        coverPdf = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arr];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        [pdfCollectionView reloadData];
    });
});
...
}
```

Generating the thumbnail:

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromPDFWithDocumentRef:(CGPDFDocumentRef)documentRef
{
    CGPDFPageRef pageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(documentRef, 1);
    CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pageRef, kCGPDFCropBox);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageRect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, CGRectGetMinX(pageRect),CGRectGetMaxY(pageRect));
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -(pageRect.origin.x), -(pageRect.origin.y));
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, pageRef);

    UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return finalImage;
}
```

Using the thumbnail:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ListPdfCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.productLabel.text  = [filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
        // Load image on a non-ui-blocking thread

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            // Assign image back on the main thread
            if ([coverPdf count] > indexPath.row)
            {
                cell.pdfImage.image = [coverPdf objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            }
        });
    });

    return cell;
}
```

I have two problems with that method :
- The first one is that the thumbnail is taking too much time to appear. When it is loaded, it works well.
- The second problem, is that the memory is continually increasing and even if I close the viewcontroller, and I come in it, it seems that the memory is not released. If I close the viewcontroller and come in 9 or 10 times, if crash the app.
[image]
In conclusion, how can I create a collection view by loading the thumbnails of the pdfs in advance and how to avoid a crash with the memory increasing ?

Thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION :**

- For the fact that it takes too much time to appear, I just replaced the DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND with the DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH. It is much better.
- For the memory leak, I used the CGPDFDocumentRelease() function just at the end of the loop like this, and all works like a charm :

  ```
      for (id cover in filePathsArray)
      {
          pdfPath = [categoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:cover];
          pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath];
          pdfRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfUrl);
          [arr addObject:[self imageFromPDFWithDocumentRef:pdfRef]];

          CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdfRef);//Line added

          NSLog(@"first process"); 
      }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have bad news for you. Memory leak is not your problem but iOS 10 memory management bug

> There is a memory management bug in iOS 10.0.1 and 10.0.2 in the CGContextDrawPDFPage() function.

You can find details here http://www.openradar.me/28415289

Also you can find useful this discussion https://github.com/vfr/Reader/issues/166

In few words possible workaround is not to create 
`CGPDFPageRef pageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(documentRef, 1);`
each time but use one CGPDFPageRef for all of your pdf files. Then set it NULL when you not needs it anymore.

***Creating thumbnails lag***

And in terms of solution for creating thumbnails. I can only suggest not to do it in this VC at all but create thumbnail for each .pdf in the app at the moment when this .pdf added to the app (or on app launch in background service if all pdfs stored in the app bundle). Then you can save this previews as .jpg or .png files with names equal to pdf names or set relationships between pdf and preview in any database or other storage if you have it in your app.
Then just reuse this previews in your collectionView.

Comment: Oh perfect, I use the CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdfRef); and it works perfectly due to the bug.

Comment: @Claudio It can be very dangerous because by default `CGPDFDocumentGetPage` returns autoreleased object (as any other CG method with Get semantic). So when bug will be fixed by Apple your manual release will cause extra release and can lead to crashes.

Comment: I will remove it when they will resolve the problem (I think that they never resolve it personnally).